# Position sticky with minimum distance from bottom of container

Tags: javascript, css, css-position, sticky

I am trying to have some content in a container positioned with some minimum distance to the bottom. In this example below, I want the blue element to stop at a certain point before reaching all the way to the bottom.

I understand I can just have two containers stacked on top of each other and only have the sticky content inside the first container. But because the container may get larger with the press of a button, this is not possible as I do want the sticky content to scroll further over the 'new' content.

In other words, I need the sticky content to have some minimum distance from the bottom of the container at all times. Is this possible in some elegant way?

I first figured it has something to do with adding the `bottom` attribute to the element as well, but this did not do anything.
I also tried some javascript approach switching from position `sticky` and `absolute` based on the users scroll position, but this worked horribly.

If anyone can help me out, that would be much appreciated.

```css
body{
  min-height:2000px;
}
.content{
  width:300px;
  background:red;
  margin-top:20px;
}
.overlayContent{
  width:100%;
  min-height:100px;
  padding:10px;
  background:blue;
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
  bottom:20px;
  z-index:999;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="undefined" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="undefined" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<body>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="overlayContent">
          
    </div>
    <p class="mt-16">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer ante enim, maximus vitae rutrum eu, ultrices ac mauris. In ac libero nisi. Suspendisse vel dictum purus. Etiam in orci orci. Donec tincidunt turpis a justo consequat, eu sodales lorem ultrices. Suspendisse dictum massa vitae elementum fringilla. Fusce est sapien, faucibus ut ultricies eget, ultrices sed turpis. Praesent ac lectus eget eros fringilla aliquam.

    <a class="btn btn-primary w-100" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
            Expand
          </a>
eu sodales lorem ultrices. Suspendisse dictum massa vitae elementum fringilla. Fusce est sapien, faucibus ut ultricies eget, ultrices sed turpis. Praesent ac lectus eget eros fringilla aliquam.
      <p>
      <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
        <div class="card card-body">
          Some content to make the original content container a bit larger.
          Some content to make the original content container a bit larger.
          Some content to make the original content container a bit larger.
          Some content to make the original content container a bit larger.
          Some content to make the original content container a bit larger.
          Some content to make the original content container a bit larger.
          Some content to make the original content container a bit larger.
          Some content to make the original content container a bit larger.
          Some content to make the original content container a bit larger.
          Some content to make the original content container a bit larger.
          Some content to make the original content container a bit larger.
          Some content to make the original content container a bit larger.
          Some content to make the original content container a bit larger.
          Some content to make the original content container a bit larger.
          Some content to make the original content container a bit larger.
          Some content to make the original content container a bit larger.
          Some content to make the original content container a bit larger.
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the situation correct, the blue box should stop before the button. Please, correct me if it's wrong.

```css
* {border:medium none; margin:0; padding:0;}
*:hover, *:active, *:focus {outline:none !important;}
html {height:100%;}
body{
  padding:0 0 20px;
  min-height:2000px;
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:row nowrap;
}
.content{
  width:300px;
  background:red;
  margin-top:20px;
}
.overlayContent{
  width:300px;
  min-height:100px;
  padding:10px;
  background:blue;
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
  bottom:20px;
  z-index:999;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="undefined" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="undefined" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<body>
  
  <div class="content">
    <div class="overlayContent">

    </div>
        
        <p class="mt-16">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer ante enim, maximus vitae rutrum eu, ultrices ac mauris. In ac libero nisi. Suspendisse vel dictum purus. Etiam in orci orci. Donec tincidunt turpis a justo consequat, eu sodales lorem ultrices. Suspendisse dictum massa vitae elementum fringilla. Fusce est sapien, faucibus ut ultricies eget, ultrices sed turpis. Praesent ac lectus eget eros fringilla aliquam.</p>
        
    <a class="btn btn-primary w-100" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
      Expand
    </a>

        <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
          <div class="card card-body">
            Some content to make the original content container a bit larger.
            Some content to make the original content container a bit larger.
            Some content to make the original content container a bit larger.
            Some content to make the original content container a bit larger.
            Some content to make the original content container a bit larger.
            Some content to make the original content container a bit larger.
            Some content to make the original content container a bit larger.
            Some content to make the original content container a bit larger.
            Some content to make the original content container a bit larger.
            Some content to make the original content container a bit larger.
            Some content to make the original content container a bit larger.
            Some content to make the original content container a bit larger.
            Some content to make the original content container a bit larger.
            Some content to make the original content container a bit larger.
            Some content to make the original content container a bit larger.
            Some content to make the original content container a bit larger.
            Some content to make the original content container a bit larger.
          </div>
        </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The blue box should go over the button and any other content in the container, including the collapsed text if the button is pressed. Only the blue box should never reach all the way till the bottom. So some fixed margin should always be present between the bottom of the container and the blue box.

Sorry if it wasn't clear and thanks for the help.

Comment: Ok, then you need to increase .content block height. And the blue block will stop on the end of it.

Comment: I see you edited your snippet and it seems to be working but that is only because the body is now not long enough to scroll further. If you set the body height to 3000 for example the box will still scroll all the way down. Or am I missing something in your answer?

Comment: I've made more changes. Now box .content takes 100% height of body. Sticky box is visible only while parent box is visible. So if .content is shorter than body sticky box will disappear. Another way is to put sticky box inside the .content box and it will be visible all the way to the bottom.